# How to flush App Engine SearchServiceFactory async operation in JUnit?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, full-text-search

I'm using App engine Standard env and my services use the [Search API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/).

So basically in my service I do something like:

```
IndexSpec indexSpec = IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName(indexName).build();
Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(indexSpec);
index.putAsync(document);
```

I'd like to implement a JUnit test to validate my document has been saved in the index.

But if I do in the same JUnit Thread:

```
...
index.putAsync(document);
index.search("");
```

it won't return my document (because I used Index#putAsync).

A simple hack is to use Thread#sleep:

```
...
index.putAsync(document);
Thread.sleep(10);
index.search("");
```

But that's really ugly.

How can I flush/execute all waiting async operations before running my search?

(I know there is a synchronous Index#put method but I want to use Index#putAsync in my service so the goal here is really to flush all waiting async operations)

Thanks

Comment: When you put a document in a index it takes some time to take propagate [https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/#Java_Consistency] it’s normal that it won’t return your document. I think you could implement a exponential backoff[https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/exponential-backoff ] to periodically retry to get the document, like is on the example[https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/java/search/#Java_Searching_for_documents_by_their_contents ] but you would be using “Thread.sleep” anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing something like that:

```
...
Future future = index.putAsync(document);
while (!future.isDone()) {
  Thread.yield();
}
index.search("");
```